# preg replace everything BUT digits over 5 in length

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

I have a string:

> 3 pk. Ready-Dough White Loaves Included $3.99 - 47500 - 00892, 48101

I want to keep only groups of digits longer than 5 characters, and if possible, any dashes or commas between them.

e.g.

> 47500-00892,48101

My first step was to strip out groups of digits < 4:

> preg_replace('/\d{1,4}/', '', $string);

My thinking was "replace any block of digits from 1 to 4 with nothing", but that doesn't do exactly what I thought. Maybe I'm just missing an operator?

Then I was going to strip out all letters and all punctuation except , and -. In my example I would've been left with a starting - because of it being in a string, but a trim() would've been fine to clean that up.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: 1. Please tag your question with the programming language you;'re using. 2. Why not split the string on the first dash `-` then you can easily remove spaces and etc.

Comment: This was in PHP.

The dashes aren't consistent. My sample code was one of many very different examples. 

I eventually answered my own question though, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had I been patient for 5 more minutes, I would've found the answer: \b

For some reason, working with digits didn't trigger that I needed to use 'word boundaries'.

```
$string = preg_replace('/\b\d{1,4}\b/', '', $string);
$string = preg_replace('/[^0-9-,]/', '', $string);
$string = trim($string, ',-');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since there's no reason to perform a replacement, you can use `preg_match_all` to take what you want and reduce the result array:

```
$re = '/\d{5,}(?:(?=\s*([-,])\s*\d{5}))?/';
$str = '3 pk. Ready-Dough White Loaves Included $3.99 - 47500 - 00892, 48101';

if ( preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER) ) {
    $result = array_reduce($matches, function ($c,$i) { return $c . implode('', $i); });
    echo $result;
}
```